# Informing colleagues that the project changes were not needed at all?

Tags: software-industry, new-job, software-development

Recently I got hired as a software developer for one company in Western Europe. I passed the technical test and during my first week started working on my first project with only few hours of training in the technology stack they are using. I have one and a half years of experience with programming, but this the first time I work with this tech stack especially.

Even though it is only the second week now, I'm satisfied with my first commits. However, towards the end of the week I noticed that one of the features I was implementing is not really compatible with one of the browsers the client was using. I suggested a fallback option which got accepted and continued with the progress.

However, when I got home and checked the feature on my home computer, it worked perfectly fine and the fallback option was probably not needed in the first place. I suspect that what caused the issue in the first place was the laptop that I was given which was probably not configured properly.

My question is, **how should I inform my colleagues during our next standup that the issue was actually my laptop and not the feature itself**? I already spent a whole day implementing the fallback option and I'm afraid that this will look unprofessional since I could've done a better job researching the issue.

Comment: What about other developers' laptops? Are you sure there's a misconfiguration - did you identify it? And can you guarantee that no other user in the world won't have the same configuration? Keep the fallback

Comment: So a company device was improperly configured or configured in such a way it wasn’t compatible with your original feature, you should identify what the conflicting configuration is, then determine the value of the fallback code you wrote.  Work with whom ever has the ability to change the configuration of the device

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're over-thinking it.

Unless your client uses laptops issued by your company, and verified compatible with the new feature, there's no way you can guarantee the fallback is redundant.

Simply present your new findings, figure out how to fix it, but affirm that you must have a fallback option, at least to get notified that the feature is not working.